# Confused with a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the limit as x approaches 0 from the right side of $f(x)$ equals $A$ and the limit as x approaches 0 from the left of $f(x)$ equals $B$.

Evaluate the limit as x approaches 0 from the right side of $f(x^3-x)$

I don't even know where to start with this one. I'm absolutely blind-sided.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous at $x=0$ from the right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? This is all the information I have. There are two functions in my question.

Comment: As this is a homework question, depending on the ammount of rigour in your course, you might have to specify that you're using the limit of a composite function theorem (and why you can apply it).

Comment: @B.S.: No, the question says nothing about the value of $f(0)$. But that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^3-x$ for small $x>0$ is negative, so $$\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x^3-x)=\lim_{x\to0^-} f(x).$$  Note the difference: $0^+$ vs $0^-$.  The answer for $x^3-x$ approaching from the right is the same as for $x$ approaching from the left.

This is enough for you to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, I added that there is another limit as it approaches from the left. Can you re-evaluate your answer?

Comment: Updated.  Let me know if you need more guidance.  I think the answer is clear now.

Comment: The answer is B right? In your question you say that it doesn't matter where it approaches, we'd get the same answer. I get two different answers. Either it's positive or negative depending on from where we approach.

Comment: $x\to0^+$ means "from the right" and $x\to0^-$ means "from the left". In the equality in this answer the RHS is the opposite of the LHS.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** for $0<x<1$, $x^3-x<0$. So when $x\searrow0^+$, you have $x^3-x\nearrow0^-$.

Comment: I think you have it backwards: $x$ approaches $0$ from above, not below. So $x^3-x$ approaches $0$ from below, not above.

Comment: Fixed -- thanks.